# undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard when building zmq (libsodium) to wasm with emscripten

Tags: c++, cmake, webassembly, emscripten, conan

I'm using emscripten to compile a c++ code to wasm, and I'm failing to incorporate zmq (I think the failing part is in libsodium) due to `undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard` error. I created a minimal reproducer, you can comfortably get it here: https://github.com/psarka/repro. I will briefly describe it bellow and will add what I tried to make it work.

### Setup

The tree is as follows:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── conanfile.txt
├── emscripten.profile
├── README.md
└── src
    ├── index.html
    └── main.cpp
```

`main.cpp` is essentially one line `zmqpp::context context;`

`CMakeLists.txt` is standard conan stuff + one emscript specific line :

```
set_target_properties(repro PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".html" LINK_FLAGS "--emrun")
```

`emscripten.profile` and `conanfile.txt` are nothing special as well.

The build instructions are:

```
conan install . -if=build -pr:h=emscripten.profile -pr:b=default --build=missing
source build/activate.sh
cmake -B build -S .
cmake --build build/ -- -j 4
```

### What I tried

I found some info on the error, and one of the suggestions (from [here](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/11228)): is to add flags
`make CFLAGS="-fstack-protector-all" LDFLAGS="-fstack-protector-all"`

I tried to add them any way I could google, and only this line in CMakeLists.txt did change something:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fstack-protector-all")
```

After this, the culprit file changed in the stack trace, but the error remained the same.

I'm unable to find and/or understand how to set the LDFLAG, or maybe I did suceed and it didn't work. I don't know :(

### Error so far

Essentially this:

```
wasm-ld: error: CMakeFiles/repro.dir/src/main.cpp.o: undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld: error: too many errors emitted, stopping now (use -error-limit=0 to see all errors)
```

Comment: As you created the repro case, I'd suggest to submit it as a Github issue to the repo (https://github.com/conan-io/conan). It seems difficult, requiring specific emscriptem knowledge, but it is worth tracking it there too.

Comment: @drodri Thanks, I'll do that!